# Spring Social Twitter search is not giving correct results

Tags: java, spring, twitter, twitter-oauth, spring-social

I am using Spring Social to search the twitter for a particular #tags. The resulting tweets are completely different from what I obtain from the twitter website and twitter API via Spring Social.

In some cases, the the search via Spring social renders zero tweets, where as same search will give some results on twitter.(example search keyword: `#globalrecruit`)

Search controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="twitter/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Tweet> searchTwitter(@RequestParam("query") String query, Model model) {       
    return twitter.searchOperations().search(query).getTweets();
}
```

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?

Comment: @ork nope.. Still could not figure out the solution! :(

Comment: Because you were comparing it to the "Top" tab in Twitter perhaps?